# Local Angular build succeed but Gitlab runner Angular build fail

Tags: angular, gitlab

I have an Angular project that I would like to run on Gitlab Page.

When I run: `ng build --prod` locally, the build succeeds.

My `.gitlab-ci.yaml`:

```
image: node:8.12.0

pages:
  cache:
    paths:
    - node_modules/

  stage: deploy
  script:
  - npm install -g @angular/cli@6.2.1
  - npm install
  - ng build
  - mv dist/ProjectName/* public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

When the Gitlab CI/CD pipeline runs, it fails with:

> ERROR in app/app.module.ts(116,5): Error during template compile of
>   'AppModule'
>
> Could not resolve ./services/user.service relative to
>   /builds/JulienRouse/ProjectName/src/app/app.module.ts..
>
> src/app/services/Auth.service.ts(3,29): error TS2307: Cannot find
>   module './user.service'.
>
> src/app/app.component.ts(6,29): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module './services/user.service'.
>
> src/app/home/home.component.ts(4,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module
>   '../services/user.service'.
>
> src/app/result/result.component.ts(4,29):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module '../services/user.service'.
>
> src/app/models/riskQuestion.model.ts(1,29): error TS2307: Cannot find
>   module '../services/user.service'.
>
> src/app/survey/survey.component.ts(4,29): error TS2307: Cannot find
>   module '../services/user.service'.
>
> src/app/infos-recap/infos-recap.component.ts(2,29): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module '../services/user.service'.
>
> src/app/auth/signup/signup.component.ts(5,29): error TS2307: Cannot
>   find module '../../services/user.service'.
>
> src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts(4,29): error TS2307: Cannot
>   find module '../services/user.service'.
>
> src/app/payment/payment-recap/payment-recap.component.ts(2,29): error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module '../../services/user.service'.
>
> src/app/payment/payment-history/payment-history.component.ts(2,29):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../services/user.service'.
>
> src/app/payment/payment-settings/payment-settings.component.ts(4,29):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module 'src/app/services/user.service'.
>
> src/app/services/auth-guard.service.ts(4,29): error TS2307: Cannot
>   find module './user.service'.
>
> src/app/services/notAuth-guard.service.ts(4,29): error TS2307: Cannot
>   find module './user.service'.
>
> src/app/services/surveyCompleted-guard.service.ts(4,29): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module './user.service'.
>
> src/app/services/surveyNotCompleted-guard.service.ts(4,29): error
>   TS2307: Cannot find module './user.service'.
>
> src/app/app.module.ts(23,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module
>   './services/user.service'.
>
> ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

So the compiler tells me there is something wrong with `app.module.ts` but why would it build successfully locally then? I'm a bit lost here.

Here is the `app/app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ExtraOptions } from '@angular/router';

// Component
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { SurveyComponent } from './survey/survey.component';
import { ResultComponent } from './result/result.component';
import { InfosRecapComponent } from './infos-recap/infos-recap.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './auth/signup/signup.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './auth/signin/signin.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { PaymentRecapComponent } from './payment/payment-recap/payment-recap.component';
import { PaymentHistoryComponent } from './payment/payment-history/payment-history.component';
import { PaymentSettingsComponent } from './payment/payment-settings/payment-settings.component';
import { ProductDescriptionComponent } from './product-description/product-description.component';

// Services
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth-guard.service';
import { BankService } from './services/Bank.service';
import { AuthService } from './services/Auth.service';
import { NotAuthGuard } from './services/notAuth-guard.service';
import { SurveyCompletedGuard } from './services/surveyCompleted-guard.service';
import { SurveyNotCompletedGuard } from './services/surveyNotCompleted-guard.service';
import { ProductService } from './services/Product.service';

// Material Angular
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';

// i18n
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';

// Charts
import { NgxChartsModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';



// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  const url = window.location.href;

  if (url.includes('someURL')) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/ProjectName/assets/i18n/', '.json');
  }
  else if(url.includes('someOtherURL')) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '/ProjectName/assets/i18n/', '.json');
  }
   else {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
  }
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'signin', canActivate: [NotAuthGuard], component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'signup', canActivate: [NotAuthGuard], component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'projectName', canActivate: [AuthGuard, SurveyNotCompletedGuard], component: SurveyComponent },
  // { path: 'result', canActivate:[AuthGuard], component: ResultComponent },
  { path: 'user-update', canActivate: [AuthGuard, SurveyCompletedGuard], component: InfosRecapComponent },
  { path: 'infos-recap', canActivate: [AuthGuard, SurveyCompletedGuard], component: InfosRecapComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', canActivate: [AuthGuard, SurveyCompletedGuard], component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'payment-recap/:id', canActivate: [AuthGuard, SurveyCompletedGuard], component: PaymentRecapComponent },
  { path: 'product-description/:id', canActivate: [AuthGuard, SurveyCompletedGuard], component: ProductDescriptionComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home' }
];

const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
  anchorScrolling: 'enabled', // Doesn't work properly on info-recap?
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    SurveyComponent,
    ResultComponent,
    InfosRecapComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    SigninComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    PaymentHistoryComponent,
    PaymentRecapComponent,
    PaymentSettingsComponent,
    ProductDescriptionComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,        // Material Angular
    MatStepperModule,               // Material Angular
    MatFormFieldModule,             // Material Angular
    MatInputModule,                 // Material Angular
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, routerOptions),
    NgxChartsModule,                // Charts

    // i18n
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    UserService,
    AuthGuard,
    NotAuthGuard,
    SurveyCompletedGuard,
    SurveyNotCompletedGuard,
    BankService,
    AuthService,
    ProductService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Any help appreciated, if you need any more information I'll be happy to give them to you.

Comment: Seems there is something wrong with the 'user.service' module. Have you checked this file is correctly pushed to the branch master in your Gitlab remote?

Comment: In the master branch I find it at ` projectName/src/app/services/User.service.ts `, where it should be. And the content of the file is the same as locally. Thanks for you input.

Comment: the name is User.service? Maybe the gitlab machine is case sensitive... this could be a reason. Have you tried to rename it to user.service.ts and see if it works?

Comment: You were right! I don,t know why it works locally and not on Gitlab but the name are case sensitive. If you may write it as an answer I'll accept your response Thanks you very much, I had totally overlooked that

Comment: I am happy this solved your problem:), I've put the solution as the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems there is something wrong with the 'user.service' module. Have you checked this file is correctly pushed to the branch master in your Gitlab remote?
If it is, check if the name is exactly 'user.service' and not 'User.service'. The Gitlab machine may be case sensitive.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Case sensitivity! What an annoying and sneaky error. This one got me, thank you!